# What is the best practise of deploying your web-application on localhost using Tomcat and Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I'm using Eclipse IDE and Tomcat instance in it for deploying my web-application on localhost.

So, when I want to write some code on server-side programming languages I open IDE and deploy an application with built-in Tomcat instance.

But today I just wanted to write some HTML and CSS stuff - smth. not connected with the above one, so there are no need for me to open my IDE and start Tomcat instance there (I think it will be very cumbersome for my purpose). Hovewer, I need Tomcat because all HTML is embedded in jsp-files and without servlet container I won't launch them.

And here is a problem. My project is in my 'eclipse-workspace' folder, but not in Tomcat 'webapps' and I need to open my IDE for deploying my project on localhost or for exporting it to the 'webapps' directory.

What I am looking for is a solution that gives me possibility to deploy my application with Tomcat, launched from command-line and in the same moment use this application as Eclipse project. Is it possible to make the move in that direction or what I misunderstood in deploying your web-application on a localhost?

Comment: look for eclipse tomcat plugin

Answer (score 0):

I think the tool you need is 'ant'

see `ant build` with appriopriate build.xml file (generated by eclipse while an export)

http://ant.apache.org/